# An AutoHotkey script to move the cursor two words

Tags: autohotkey

I'm attempting to write an AutoHotkey script that moves the cursor to the beginning of the second next word, in a similar way that Window's `ctrl + arrows` and `fn + arrows` shortcuts works.

I use very often this pair of shortcuts, but I frequently find that the first one moves the cursor too slowly and the second one too fast. So I would like to get a script that moves the caret, as described, two words instead of one (for example, when pressing `ctrl + alt + arrows`).

I've never scripted for automated actions on the keyboard before, so this is all new territory for me. I assume anyone with some experience could implement the above in a minute or two.

Comment: Generally, we don't write the code for you, but we are glad to help with a specific problem or issue. I would recommend reading through the "Getting started" section of the help documentation. https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/AutoHotkey.htm As this really only took a couple seconds, try this: `^!right::Send , ^{right 2}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have realized that it is much easier than writing an AutoHotkey script, it can be done by recording a macro in Microsoft Word.